# Mongo DB: How do I turn an array of documents into individual documents?

Tags: python, mongodb

```
{
 "teachers" : [
               {"name": "Lucy", "id": 3, course: "history"}, 
               {"name": "Mark", "id": 6, "course": "maths"}, 
               {"name": "Joan", "id": 20, course: "French"} 
               ] 
}
```

This document is in the "school" collection. I have been trying to access these imbedded documents using

```
db.school.find({teachers:{id:3}})
```

I also tried

```
db.school.find({teacher.id:3})
```

but I understand it isn't working since mongo can't look inside an embedded array.
Therefore I would like to turn these imbedded documents into individual documents. That is, remove the embedding and the "teachers" key, creating an individual document for each teacher.

The final "school" collection would be

```
{"name": "Lucy", "id": 3, "course": "history"}, 
{"name": "Mark", "id": 6, "course": "maths"}, 
{"name": "Joan", "id": 20, "course": "French"}
```

i would like to do it with python and save the new documents into a collection.

***EDIT***

this is what i have come up with for now:

```
import pymongo
import sys

connection = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://localhost", safe=True)

db = connection.hello
shows = db.school

for doc in db.school:
    for indiv in "teachers":
            try:
            db.individual.insert(indiv)
        except:
            print "Unexpected error", sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Comment: the question is; is it possible to turn 

{"teachers" : [{name:"Lucy", id:3, course:"history"}, 
{name:"Mark", id: 6, course:"maths"}, 
{name:"Joan", id:20, course:"French"} ] }

into


{name:"Lucy", id:3, course:"history"}, 
{name:"Mark", id: 6, course:"maths"}, 
{name:"Joan", id:20, course:"French"}

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean 'possible'? With python? With mongodb console or just anyhow?

Comment: i would like to do it with python and save the new documents into a collection. Sorry i'm not very clear..

Comment: Writing a python script to do this database conversion would be a valid approach. You could also do it with the mongo shell because it is a full-fledged javascript interpreter, but when you feel more comfortable with python, go for it. So what stops you from doing it?

Comment: Maybe you could just replace your data manually from old collection to a new one? Is it necessary to use a script?

Comment: yes it's necessary because there are over 3000 teachers in the collection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
school_records = db.school.find()
for i in school_records:
    for teacher in i['teachers']:
        db.individual.insert(teacher)
```

What about this?

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to make the final _id the same as the id in the original collection?

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea (if you use default ObjectId). But it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, Mongodb can find embedded documents that are in arrays:

```
db.school.find({ 'teachers.id' : 3 });
```

You can learn more about the dot notation at [mongodb documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29).

In case the goal is to return only the embedded document you can use an [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) request:

```
db.school.aggregate(
  {$match: { 'teachers.id' : 3 }}, 
  {$unwind : '$teachers'}, 
  {$project: { 
    _id: 0, 
    name: '$teachers.name',
    id: '$teachers.id', 
    course: '$teachers.course' 
  }}, 
  {$match: {id:3}}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregate command (it is in pymongo) from mongo v2.2+:

```
    fagg=db.school.aggregate([{$unwind: "$teachers"},
    {$project: {name: "$teachers.name", 
    id: "$teachers.id", course: "$teachers.course"}}])
    fagg.result.forEach(function(o){
    db.teachers.insert({_id: o.id, name: o.name, course: o.course})})
```